# How can I move a tick label only(without moving corresponding tick)?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to generate a diagram, and I use `set_ticks` and `set_ticklabels` to mark out several important values on the x-axis. But some of these labels are too close and get overlapped. But I don't know how to move these labels without moving the ticks.

Here is an illustration:

[image: overlapped tick labels]

I have tried several tricks but failed, and I haven't found an answer to this question on the Internet. Any help, thanks.

---

### Update:

The source code:

```
fig = mpl.figure( figsize=(3, 3) )              # force figsize here to reproduce the problem.
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, frameon=False)
ax.set_xlim(-0.015, 1.515)
ax.set_ylim(-0.01, 1.01)
ax.set_xticks([0, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0, 1.5])
ax.grid(True)
mpl.show()
```

And the result:

[image]

I have tried several tricks and the best one is:

```
fig = mpl.figure( figsize=(3, 3) )
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, frameon=False)
ax.set_xlim(-0.015, 1.515)
ax.set_ylim(-0.01, 1.01)
ax.set_xticks([0, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0, 1.5])
ax.set_xticklabels([0.0, "", "", 1.0, 1.5])
ax.set_xticks([0.35], minor=True)
ax.set_xticklabels(["0.3 0.4"], minor=True)
ax.grid(True)
mpl.show()
```

[image]

But there is a minor tick at x = 0.35 and I don't know how to remove it.

---

### Update 2:

OK, I found how to remove minor ticks myself:

```
for line in ax.xaxis.get_minorticklines():
    line.set_visible(False)
```

In this manner, we can utilize minor ticks to put tick labels anywhere we want.

Thanks to all warm-hearted!

Comment: It looks like the "illustration" was produced by sample code. Supplying this code will often help get more responses, better ones, and faster.

Comment: @TalKremerman: I've added some details. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your comment "..mark out several important values on the x-axis" I think you shouldn't be changing the xticks and labels, but rather add vertical lines with appropriate annotation.

This means the grid over which your data remains regular and allows you to colourise important points, you could also add the numeric values as well fairly easily.

Example

```
import pylab as py

# Plot a sinc function
delta=2.0
x=py.linspace(-10,10,100)
y=py.sinc(x-delta)

# Mark delta
py.axvline(delta,ls="--",color="r")
py.annotate(r"$\delta$",xy=(delta+0.2,-0.2),color="r",size=15)
py.plot(x,y)
```

[image: Simple sinc and annotation]

Comment: OK, I'll use this suggestion if no other better solutions. Thank you~

Comment: This doesn't solves the question's problem, it is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 11):

For someone looking for an answer to the original question:
It could be an option to change the alignment of the tick_label.

This is explained in detail in an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/centered_ticklabels.html) on the matplotlib webpage. Basically in the case above one would use

```
ax.get_xaxis().majorTicks[1].label1.set_horizontalalignment('right')
ax.get_xaxis().majorTicks[2].label1.set_horizontalalignment('left')
```

to move the labels away from each other

Answer (score 3):

As a strict response to the question asked, you can get the specific tick and use [set_pad()](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.Tick.set_pad)

```
ax.get_xaxis().majorTicks[2].set_pad()
```

I think that a better practice would be to use [autofmt_xdate](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.autofmt_xdate)

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Which rotates the xtick labels nicely and allow most texts to fit nicely without overlapping.
If they still overlap - it means that those ticks are very close together. And then the question which arises is what good would two ticks so closely together would do to the viewer of your plot?

Comment: `set_pad` can only move the tick vertically, and I've tried `set_position`, but only y-coordinate take effect.

Comment: This doesn't solves the question's problem, your answer's code only moves the tick label vertically.