# Matplotlib: Move ticklabels between ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a visualization of a confusion matrix using matplotlib.
Parameters to the methods shown below are the class labels (alphabet),
the classification results as a list of lists (conf_arr) and an output filename.
I am pretty happy with the result so far, with one last problem:

I am not able to center the axis tick labels between the gridlines.
If I pass the extent parameter to the imshow method as below,
the grid is aligned as I would like it to be.
If I comment it out, the grid is missaligned but the labels are were I would like
them to be.
I think I need a way to move the ticklabel between the associated tick and the next tick
but I do not know if and how this is possible.

To summarize, I want the grid/ticks like in the left image, but the ticklabels
positioned like in the right image:

[image]

```
def create_confusion_matrix(alphabet, conf_arr, outputname):
    norm_conf = []
    width = len(conf_arr)
    height = len(conf_arr[0])
    for i in conf_arr:
        a = 0
        tmp_arr = []
        a = sum(i, 0)
        for j in i:
            tmp_arr.append(float(j)/float(a))
        norm_conf.append(tmp_arr)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
    #fig = plt.figure()
    plt.clf()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_aspect(1)
    ax.grid(which='major')
    res = ax.imshow(np.array(norm_conf), cmap=plt.cm.binary, 
                    interpolation='none', aspect='1', vmax=1,
                    ##Commenting out this line sets labels correctly,
                    ##but the grid is off
                    extent=[0, width, height, 0]
                    )
    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.2)
    cb = fig.colorbar(res, cax=cax)

    #Axes
    ax.set_xticks(range(width))
    ax.set_xticklabels(alphabet, rotation='vertical')
    ax.xaxis.labelpad = 0.5
    ax.set_yticks(range(height))
    ax.set_yticklabels(alphabet, rotation='horizontal')
    #plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(outputname, format='png')
```

The produced image looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Does the solution in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16162514/how-can-i-move-a-tick-label-onlywithout-moving-corresponding-tick) work for you?

Comment: Possible related [Centering x-tick labels between tick marks in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158382/centering-x-tick-labels-between-tick-marks-in-matplotlib)

Comment: This is a clearly written, well-worded question! (+1) Not sure why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you've noticed, they're centered by default and you're overriding the default behavior by specifying `extent=[0, width, height, 0]`.

There are a number of ways to handle this. One is to use `pcolor` and set the edgecolors and linestyles to look like the gridlines (you actually need `pcolor` and not `pcolormesh` for this to work).  However, you'll have to change the extents to get the ticks in the center as `imshow` does by default.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((10,10))
labels = 'abcdefghij'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.pcolor(data, cmap='gray', edgecolor='black', linestyle=':', lw=1)
fig.colorbar(im)

# Shift ticks to be at 0.5, 1.5, etc
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set(ticks=np.arange(0.5, len(labels)), ticklabels=labels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could turn on the minor grid and place it at the pixel boundaries.  Because you want fixed labels, we'll just set everything manually. Otherwise, a `MultipleLocator` would make more sense:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((10,10))
labels = 'abcdefghij'

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='gray', interpolation='none')
fig.colorbar(im)

# Set the major ticks at the centers and minor tick at the edges
locs = np.arange(len(labels))
for axis in [ax.xaxis, ax.yaxis]:
    axis.set_ticks(locs + 0.5, minor=True)
    axis.set(ticks=locs, ticklabels=labels)

# Turn on the grid for the minor ticks
ax.grid(True, which='minor')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, this solves my problem perfectly! :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively: have you tried `im = ax.matshow(data, cmap='gray')` instead of `imshow()`? This should also place the ticklabels on the correct position.